# Net status: NetConnection.Connect.Failed on localhost (window).

Tags: ant, java, red5

I have downloaded **JDK 1.7**, **ant** and **red5**.

The following pathes are set in system environment:

1. `JAVA_HONE=c:/programs/java_home`
2. `ANT_HOME=c:/programs/ant_home`

ant, java and red5 are in same c: drive, and red5 services are started.

The **Oflademo.war** file is copied to `red5/webapps`. I checked the URL in browser `localhost:5080` but no result.

What am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
 and red5 services are started
```

What makes you think that it is started?
If localhost:5080 gives no result in fact red5 is not started at all.

Also it would be needed that you give us the red5 version, and the oflaDemo version that you are using, maybe those versions do not fit together.

Also make sure if red5 is really started, to debug *anything* you always should check the red5.log, error.log and eventually oflademo.log if there is one created for this webapp.

Sebastian